# How to translate require to es6 import/export for node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, npm, ecmascript-6

I want to use the pokedex-promise for a pokemonapi but the [docs](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokedex-promise-v2) only show you how to require it in vanilla javascript style:

```
npm install pokedex-promise-v2 --save
var Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2');
var P = new Pokedex();
```

How do I use import to get this module? I've tried

```
import {Pokedex} from 'pokedex-promise-v2'
```

and

```
import Pokedex from 'pokedex-promise-v2'
```

but both throw errors with the module:

```
in ./~/tough-cookie/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/tough-cookie/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/jlei/Desktop/pokeapp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
 @ ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40
```

Comment: I think your code is not transpiring properly. can you share transpiler code part. nd mention the error in the question.

Comment: what is the transpiler code part? is that something from babel? i've added the error

Comment: you need to use webpack or gulp or anything for that purpose.

Comment: It seems you are using webpack. Some code is trying to include a `package.json` file. In order for this to work you have to configure  `json-loader` or configure webpack to ignore that file. The error has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) for webpack. Install via NPM:

```
npm install --save json-loader
```

Then add it to your webpack config like so:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        /* ...other loaders */
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json',
        },
    ],
},
```

This will allow webpack to load the json file when it's bundling.